# $("article").filter*(while).each(repeat_me) - loop while filter matches

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have a custom function repeatedly called as long as a custom filter function matches.

use case:

```
// filter
function overflow() { 
    return this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight;
}

// apply
$("article").filter(overflow).css_calc({fontSize: -1});
```

Is there a generic way in jQuery to call the subsequent function ***as long as*** the filter matches? Or wasn't there something to call the *preceeding* function multiple times? *Any way* to loop in a jQuery function chain?

Or otherwise; how would you write something like an `.each_while()` combo that does the usual .each() but also performs a while() on each element as long as said .filter() matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not fully understand your question, but I think you can get with you want using simple imperative programming:

```
// filter
function overflow() { 
    return this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight;
}

while($("article").filter(overflow).length > 0)
    $("article").filter(overflow).css_calc({fontSize: -1});
```

A more elegant solution escapes me at the moment, though.

Comment: Indeed, that while does the trick. (lol, I was too immersed in jQuery semantics and searching for an elaborate high-level solution.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to periodically call your code at regular intervals.

```
function update() {
    $("article").filter(overflow).css_calc({fontSize: -1});
}

var timer = setInterval(update, 200); // update every 200ms
```

To clear the update, call

```
clearInterval(timer);
```